# Dovecot listens on different interfaces for different services

Tags: dovecot

I'm just setting up Dovecot 2 and I wanted to have it listen on port `993` for `imaps` on all interfaces and listen on port `143` for normal `imap` only on the loopback interface.

That way I'd have less publicly open ports and can still use a non-tls connection for a webmail client running on the same server.

I can change the listening ports here:

```
Service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    address = localhost
    #port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    #port = 993
    #ssl = yes
  }}
```

and with `listen = *, ::` I can change the interface, but not separately for different ports. the listen command does not work inside the `inet_listener` block.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I actually found the answer in some commit log for dovecot while typing the question.
The relevant command is `address = [...]` not `listen`.

So it now looks like this:

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    address = localhost
    #port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    #port = 993
    #ssl = yes
  }}
```

Source: http://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot-cvs/2009-August/014295.html